# Show that the function $f(z)=1/z$ transforms a circle centered at the origin in the $xy$ plane in a circle centered at the origin in the $uv$ plane

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry

Show that the function $f (z) = 1 / z$ transforms a circle centered at the origin in the $xy$ plane in a circle centered at the origin in the $uv$ plane. Someone can give me a clue to start the demostration, I have the doubt if I separate function in its real and imaginary parts and independently plot.

I try to separate the real and imaginary part of the funcion then:

$z=\frac{1}{x+iy}=\frac{i}{x+iy}*\frac{x-iy}{x-iy}=\frac{x-iy}{x^2+y^2}$ then $u=\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}$ and $v=\frac{-y}{x^2+y^2}$ How can this help me??

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\;z\in\Bbb C\;$ is on a circle centered at the origin, say of radius $\;r\;$, iff $\;|z|=r\;$

Well, now check what happens to the above $\;z\;$ under $\;f(z):=\frac1z\;$ ...

Answer (score 1):

The transformation w=f(z)=1/z is called inversion where z must be a nonzero complex number. Let w=u+iv be the image of z=x+iy under the transformation 1/z. Next we can see that  x=u/(u^2+v^2) and y=-v/(u^2+v^2).We can show  that the mapping 1/z transforms circles and lines into circles and lines.